# Ignore specific value inside html attribute by Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with html templates that have variables inside. These variables are going to be replaced with some values (by regular expression). But some variables I want to exclude.

Here is my test html code:

```
data-coupon-patern="test {{SALE}} test"
test {{SALE}} test "
test {{SALE}} test 
data-coupon-patern="test {{SALE}} test"
data-text="test {{SALE}} test
```

My goal is replacing all {{SALE}} (that's how I identify variables) that is not inside data-coupon-patern attribute, using regular expression. In this attribute {{SALE}} should not be replaced.

I have tried on my own and I get this regex:
`/(?![^"]*"){{[\s|&nbsp;]*Sale[\s|&nbsp;]*}}/gi`

But with this, I get replaced only last {{SALE}} in html.

I hope some wizards (someone who knows regular expression brilliant) will se this post and help me with this issue :) (if you know regexp - you are really wizard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by switching from a lookahead to lookbehind for the first part of your expression and updating the contents of the lookbehind expression.

Here's the updated expression:

```
/(?<!(data-coupon-patern="[^"]*)){{[\s|&nbsp;]*sale[\s|&nbsp;]*}}/gi
```

This will look for the `{{sale}}` pattern as long as it is not preceded by `data-coupon-patern="` without a closing quote.

Output when replaced with "XXX" on the string you gave:

```
data-coupon-patern="test {{SALE}} test"
test XXX test "
test XXX test 
data-coupon-patern="test {{SALE}} test"
data-text="test XXX test
```

Note that if you're planning on running this in the browser, lookbehind is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=regexp%20lookbehind) in all browsers.

Comment: Wow! It works! But it didn't work correct on https://regex101.com/, thats strange for me a little bit... Thank you for a very useful answer! But.. If there any solution that will be supported in most browsers? I would be nice if the solution will also supports IE and Safari (desktop and mobile)

Comment: `[\s|&nbsp;]*` is an error here. It should be `(?:\s|&nbsp;)*`.